# How to return an image to client side?

Tags: java, spring

I'm need a little help with a project that I'm doing its something like 9gag, I am trying to return a JSON objects in which there are some data and an image.

I've tried doing it couple of ways, returning the image in byte array and set the GetMapping annotation to produce = "image/jpeg". Also I've tried doing it with Base64 but since I'm new to using Base64 I'm not entirely sure that I am using it correctly.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/")
    public List<PostDTO> browseAll() throws IOException {
        List<Media> dbMedia = mediaRepo.findAll();
        List<PostDTO> postDTOS = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Media media : dbMedia){
            postDTOS.add(media.convertToPostDTO());
        }
        for (PostDTO post : postDTOS){
            post.setFile(returnImage());
        }
        return postDTOS;
    }
    private String returnImage() throws IOException {
        List<Media> media = mediaRepo.findAll();
        for (Media file : media){
            File newImage = new File(file.getDir());
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(newImage);
            String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fis.readAllBytes());
            String imgData = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Base64Utils.decodeFromString(encoded);

            return imgData;

        }
        return "failed";
    }
```

By doing it with produce = "image/jpec" i get this -- "Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]" Also I'm using Postman for testing purposes.
Also here how one Json object looks like, at "file" I want the actual image.

```
    {
        "author": "Uponn",
        "title": null,
        "likes": 0,
        "file": "data:image/jpeg;base64,[B@3acfd4dd",
        "uploadTime": null
    },
```

Comment: Do you want ot get the image or a json which contains image and data ?

Comment: json that contains image and data.

Comment: Have you got this kind of json data/response from any other sites ? or do you want to create like this ?

Comment: I would like for mine to be like that. Haven't checked other site's json responses tho. Why? Its not good way of doing it?

Comment: You have to think, even if you are able to generate how will javascript convert that json message to display both image and textual data ?

Comment: @Sambit not sure how this could JS could convert it, so I'm guessing it is not possible, so if I send them the byte array from the image would they be able to covert it?

Comment: I am also thinking the same, that is why I have mentioned there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the above discussion and if my understanding is correct, you need to send the image to the front-end engineers so that they will be able to display in the web page. I provide below the code snippet, you can try.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/showImage", produces = "image/jpg")
  public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImageAsResponseEntity(
      @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName) {
    String dirPath = "some path in your drive/";
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    InputStream in = null;
    byte[] media = new byte[0];
    try {
      in = new FileInputStream(dirPath + fileName);
      media = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(media, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return responseEntity;
  }
```

Comment: Which exact class for IOUtils are you using since the one I have(org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.IOUtils) doesnt have .toByteArray method?

Comment: Apache Commons IO

Comment: It works for sure but only for one picture however in my case since I return couple of objects with each of its own picture it doesn't seem to work it just returns the byte array of the pictures. Well w/e I will try to figure it out thanks for the help. :)